# Using libarchive Gives Undefined Symbol Errors

Tags: c, gcc, libarchive

I must be missing something simple. I am getting 'undefined symbol: ...' for any libarchive function that my program calls.

Also, attempting to compile one of the example programs using the recommended command:

`gcc -Wall -o tarfilter tarfilter.c -larchive -lz -lbz2`

gives compile time 'undefined reference' errors. E.g

`` undefined reference to `archive_read_support_filter_all' ``

System is Fedora 16, libarchive version is 3.1. libarchive was already built in, so I initially did a yum install of libarchive-devel. When this gave the errors described above, I downloaded the source from github & built it but no difference was apparent.

Any clues as to what I am not configuring correctly would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Get latest libarchive and build it

from http://libarchive.org/downloads/

Steps:

```
$ tar xzf libarchive-xx.tar.gz
$ cd libarchive-xx
$ ./configure
$ make
$ make check
$ make install
```